# Backbone: Adding routes to router from view classes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way for me to add routes dynamically in backbone. I have views that get added dynamically based on permissions for a specific user. I'd like to be able to have the view class add its routes when instantiated instead of having to define all the routes in the router (I am using a single app-wide router).

I tried using the route method described in the backbone router documentation but when I then inspect the router's "routes" object I don't see the added route.

I suspect you are gonna say I can just create a new router per view... that could be it but I would prefer not to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried using the route method described in the backbone router documentation but when I then inspect the router's "routes" object I don't see the added route.

The Router's routes object is just the hash you passed into the extends function.

The actual routes get added to the Backbone.history object.

So, when you use the Router.route() function, its not going to modify the router's Routes hash, but it will actually add the route to the Backbone.history, and it will work as expected.

```
Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "help":                 "help",    // #help
    "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
    "search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #search/kiwis/p7
  },
  help: function() {
    console.log("help");       
  },
  search: function(query, page) {
    console.log("search",query,page);
  },
  new: function() {
    console.log("new");
  }
});

Main = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    initialize: function() {
        app.route('new','new');
    },
    render: function() {
      return this;   
    }
});

​app = new Workspace();
Backbone.history.start();
main = new Main();
app.navigate('new',{trigger:true});  //=> "new"
```

Live example at: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardmsmith/XsDQu/4/